# Playframework execution context : can I limit queue size?

Tags: playframework, akka

I'm using a separated execution context to do some blocking actions in background (calling a blocking API to call an external Flume server).

```
flume{
  context = {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 300
      parallelism-max = 300
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that sometimes the flume server can crash, the number of waiting tasks in the Akka queue can grow and cause memory issues. Is there a way to limit the queue for this exeecution context?

Maybe something like this ? :

```
 mailbox-capacity = 1000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A soultion is to replace the `fork-join-executor` context by a `thread-pool-executor` :

```
flume{
  context = {
    thread-pool-executor {
      core-pool-size-min = 300
      core-pool-size-min = 300
      max-pool-size-min = 300
      max-pool-size-max = 300
      task-queue-size = 1000
      task-queue-type = "linked"
    }
  }
}
```